# Interstellar war using transfer booths, novella length

Tags: story-identification

Serialization, likely Omni, possibly Analog, likely early 1980s.

Space war, Earth and unknown aliens. Both use interstellar transporter booths. Small versions, large enough for cameras and similar, are shot to nearby stars. When they arrive they turn on, connect to Earth, and start sending back data. If the system proves interesting, they transfer in parts and use them to build a larger booth, and then use that to make a larger one, and then...

I recall two bits:

The protagonist is part of a group that goes through booths when they enter new systems. A booth has collided with a planet that seems to have an atmosphere and he's the guy that has to go through. When he arrives he realizes it's a trap, and as a very brief encounter with an alien, who's arm he crushes before transporting out.

The second is the end of the portion I read, which I guess was the first half/third of the whole. A new booth arrives in a system where the enemy has also just arrived, and a race breaks out between the two to get their largest booths in-system. However, a General is arguing this is the only chance to attempt peace talks. And that's the last page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds an awful lot like *Behold the Stars* by Kenneth Bulmer, which was published in 1965 per ISFDB. No serialization is listed, however.

This story was suggested as an answer (but not accepted) to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18885/trying-to-identify-name-of-1970s-space-opera-novel-powered-armor), which does not seem like it as good of a match.

It definitely matches on the major plot points and concepts, particularly the "beachhead" of an invasion involving sending through materials to quickly construct new booths.

The part with the booth on a planet surface is a key part of the story:

> He stepped out the far door, adjusting his body to the anticipated
>   near free-fall conditions in the carrier and fell full length on his
>   face, his body crushed down by a stunning and unexpected and
>   altogether terrifying acceleration.
>
> The breath had been thumped out of his lungs by the drop. He shoved up
>   on hands and knees against the force dragging him down, feeling the
>   blood pounding crazily behind his eyes, the drag on his muscles, the
>   loosely sagging feel of his stomach muscles. Then all idea that
>   acceleration was clawing at him was dispelled.
>
> He was kneeling on a muddy ground, on earth and clay and a short squat
>   mossy growth blotching that ground, and around his as he slowly
>   rotated his head to look, dragging against that inexorable force, he
>   saw squat scaled trees and dripping branches and dangling fronds of
>   metallic creepers, and in his ears from his outside pickups the sound
>   of dripping water and sloshing mud and the insane chirruping of some
>   unseen animal life mocked him.
>
> He was on planet!

... though it is quickly explained that the "box" was more likely placed on the surface by the enemy than that it had survived a crash:

> *How had the box come here?*
>
> The first and obvious answer lay in what Lazenby had been saying: the
>   carrier had been trapped by the gravitational pull of a small red star
>   and had fallen onto the surface of a planet. But that was absurd. Even
>   if the carrier had not been traveling at something like point four of
>   c, even if it had just fallen onto the planet from a simple orbit, it
>   would have been vaporized, smashed, utterly destroyed.
>
> The boxes were built ruggedly; but even their armor couldn't stand up
>   to that type of punishment.
>
> So -- the box had been brought here.

The protagonist is involved in an ambush there but escapes back through, in a close call featuring the crushed hand that you remember:

> The door began to close.
>
> Two inches from the jamb the door hesitated. A hand -- a non-human
>   hand with three fingers and a thumb clad in an armored mitten-type
>   glove -- appeared around the edge of the door. The muzzle of a weapon
>   snouted suddenly into view through the two inch crack.
>
> Ward flung himself sideways, jerked his exo-skeleton up to full power,
>   stamped down on the retaining armored hand and heard the crunch as he
>   mashed it flat.

The ending features the "General's" (Marshal Levy) argument that peace with the aliens was only possible after an adequate show of force, which had now been accomplished:

> "Major Tracy on the line, sir!"
>
> "... cease fire. The Gershmi are sending in a truce party. Every
>   indication is that they want to call a full-scale armistice. Awaiting
>   further instructions."
>
> Marshal Levy lumbered to his feet. His face beamed. "That's what I've
>   been waiting to hear! Now we can talk friendship with the Gershmi! Now
>   we can talk about allocating the planets in dispute. We are two strong
>   alien races talking as equals and neither side will suffer. We shall
>   reach an equitable understanding." He walked around to the bowed form
>   of Old Man Ransome and put a hand on his shoulder. "This is what you
>   wanted, I know. So did we all. But there are right ways and wrong ways
>   of getting it. Not until every single thinking being in space is
>   prepared to be true friends with every other can your philanthropic
>   wishes come true. Until then we must go on as we are, standing up for
>   our own rights and respecting those of others."
>
> "But war..."
>
> "Is hateful and vile. One day we'll do without it. But with
>   instantaneous matter transmission as the normal method of
>   communication in the galaxy we're going to bump up against people
>   still thinking in barbarous terms. We of Earth must be ready."

Comment: Reading it now on GBooks... I think you nailed it.